# Docker failed to register layer

Tags: docker

I was trying to pull mysql image with `docker pull mysql` when my computer got struck. I had to restart my computer, but after restarting and trying to run mysql container with the command `docker run -d  mysql` I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to find image 'mysql:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/mysql
5040bd298390: Pull complete 
55370df68315: Pull complete 
fad5195d69cc: Pull complete 
a1034a5fbbfc: Pull complete 
17f3570b42ae: Pull complete 
6bf4b16e5339: Pull complete 
9700c9731729: Pull complete 
f2fea9c5b632: Pull complete 
2f8101f5336d: Extracting    935 B/935 B
0dc8f8a1031a: Download complete 
a1b9627588c7: Download complete 
docker: failed to register layer: rename /var/lib/docker/image/aufs/layerdb/tmp/layer-721305262 /var/lib/docker/image/aufs/layerdb/sha256/06dd4f9415b3f89d3fb1138623cebb7245affc9410611552c6fb52b091587a2e: directory not empty.
See 'docker run --help'.
3b17db599af1654ddb251295a55988121350a88c8176db24ddfe44f9194edb0c
```

The docker version is 1.12.3

I reckon the aufs is corrupted because of restart, but I dont know how to fix. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like there is a remnant from the past. Delete it:

```
rm -fr /var/lib/docker/image/aufs/layerdb/sha256/06dd4f9415b3f89d3fb1138623cebb7245affc9410611552c6fb52b091587a2e
```

Then try:

```
docker pull mysql
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but still get same error but this time with new sha256/<new_id>, so I tried this and also uninstalled and installed docker again and that worked for me

Comment: Restoring docker to system defaults worked for me (Docker icon -> Preferences -> Reset). I tried rm -rf and docker prunes without success.

Answer (score 13):

you need to clean build cache

you can run

```
docker image prune --all
```

also you can run

```
docker system prune --all
```

be careful last command will remove not used volumes

Comment: This is what I needed.  I removed the volumes in a wrong way previously.  uninstall / reinstall did not help.  After system prune, everything is back to normal

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with Arch, I guess it happens sometime with a kernel update.
Just reboot, and if the problem is the same as me, it might fix ;)

Comment: This was the only correct solution on the whole internet

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem and apparently my Local Disk had ran out of storage. Check that first before clearing up stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when my computer crashed while running

```
docker-compose pull
```

I tried @nehal-j-wani's answer but it failed. I needed to delete all the files that had been created today.

```
find /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/layerdb/sha256/* -type f -mtime 0 -exec rm {} \;
```

I was then able to run the pull command correctly.

Comment: This almost worked for me, except there were also a few empty older directories. A `cd` to the `sha256` directory (the path was slightly different in my install) followed by a `rmdir *` did the trick. There will be many error messages for the non-emopty directories, that is OK.  (In my case disk quota ran out during a previous deploy, causing the scennario).

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the target drive for wsl-2 is almost full (something i did not notice!). Consequently both the Docker client and WSL-2 fail to respond resulting in a reboot. Once refreshed I uninstalled Docker and started again. Seems overkill but it was the only working solution i could find.

At the same time ensure your WSL-2 images for Docker (if not backed up) are unregistered and make space available for the 'pull'.